# missing std::runtime_error in qt+mingw

Tags: qt, mingw, runtime-error

I've tried to compile the following code using Qt(4.6.3) + MinGW:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <exception>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    throw std::runtime_error("");

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

... and got this error:

```
..\untitled11\main.cpp:6: error: 'runtime_error' is not a member of 'std'
```

Project created from scratch(console application), the pro file:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = untitled11
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Tried to compile this using Qt+MSVC2008 compiler - works fine.

This is a standard exception, have no idea why is missing.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`<exception>` defines only the base `std::exception`class; if you want child classes like `std::runtime_error`, you must include the `<stdexcept>` header.

Comment: It exists, and contains base `std::exception` class, while `<stdexcept>` contains standard child exception classes. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/

Comment: +1000 it was driving me crazy when using `std::invalid_argument` (on Ubuntu, gcc 4.7). Thank you!